# Expo-router with webpack error "Multiple files match route name". Can't bundle or deploy app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo

I'm trying to deploy a react native web app built with expo and expo-router to Vercel. Part of the process involves using Webpack to bundle the code. Up until now I've been developing using metro and its been working fine.

I am unable to get the project to build using webpack. I think the issue lies in my root level index.js file and the [Groups](https://expo.github.io/router/docs/features/routing#groups) feature of the router.

The docs for expo router say to have
`import "expo-router/entry";`  at the top of the file.

If I do this I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '..\..\app'
  10 |   typeof window === "undefined" ? React.Fragment : Head.Provider;
  11 |
> 12 | const ctx = require.context(process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT);
     |            ^
  13 |
  14 | // Must be exported or Fast Refresh won't update the context
  15 | export function App() {
```

The [troubleshooting page](https://expo.github.io/router/docs/troubleshooting) of the docs leads me to believe I should replace the contents of my index.js file with this:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { ExpoRoot } from "expo-router";

export function App() {
  const ctx = require.context("./app");
  return <ExpoRoot context={ctx} />;
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

After doing this I get several errors for

```
Multiple files match the route name...
```

[This happens even with the most basic of setups.](https://github.com/MLaidlawScott/webpack-min-reproduce)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now (March 2023) expo-router does not support bundling with webpack. This is what was causing the errors I was seeing.

So reverting back to the default of having metro as the bundler and a root level index.js consisting of just `import "expo-router/entry";`, to deploy this app what I did was:

- run the `vercel` cli command in the root of the project to set up a new project
- change the `build command` to `npx expo export -p web`
- change the output dir to `./dist`
- move the vercel.json to the root of the project. It should look like this:

  {
  "routes": [
  { "handle": "filesystem" },
  { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/index.html" }
  ]
  }